# Stack Smashing when returning pointer to array

Tags: c, calloc, stack-smash

my function *neldermead* looks like this:

```
double * neldermead (double data[], double (*function)(int, double, double, double, double, double),
double ia1, double ia2, double ia3, double ia4, double ia5, double rad, int k) {

...

printf("8\n");
double * xout = malloc(5 * sizeof(double));

xout[0] = x[0][0];  
xout[1] = x[1][0]; 
xout[2] = x[2][0];  
xout[3] = x[3][0];  
xout[4] = x[4][0];

printf("10\n");  
return xout;
}
```

The function is called as such:

```
...
double * newX;
printf("11\n");  
newX = neldermead (data,  &function1, F1A1, F1A2, F1A3, F1A4, F1A5, 10, 10000);
printf("12\n");  
...
```

The output is as follows:

```
11
8
10
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

With *-fno-stack-protector* the code works fine.

Is there something wrong with how I returned the array or what?

////////////////////////////////////

I modified the code to do return by reference.

my function *neldermead* looks like this:

```
double * neldermead (double * xout, double data[], double (*function)(int, double, double, double, double, double),
double ia1, double ia2, double ia3, double ia4, double ia5, double rad, int k) {

...

printf("8\n");


xout[0] = x[0][0];  
xout[1] = x[1][0]; 
xout[2] = x[2][0];  
xout[3] = x[3][0];  
xout[4] = x[4][0];

printf("9\n");  

}
```

The function is called as such:

```
...
double newX[5];
printf("10\n");  
neldermead (newX, data,  &function1, F1A1, F1A2, F1A3, F1A4, F1A5, 10, 10000);
printf("11\n");  
...
```

The output is as follows:

```
10
8
9
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Damn, didn't help.

Comment: coding style: usually, you'd want the function that malloc's memory to take ownership, but that's not the problem here, most likely.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the code you posted, but there could be a problem elsewhere in the function. Could you post the complete code to neldermead please?

Comment: How are you allocating for and filling the `x[][]` array?

Comment: Your function takes 5 parameters in declaration, you are not passing them

Comment: It would be best to put together a short complete example as the issue is likely in the code you didn't show.

Comment: weirdly, using return by reference gives less accuracy than return by calloc.

Answer (score 0):

The function

```
 double (*function)(int, double, double, double, double, double)
```

Takes parameters. When function returns, it cleans up the stack.  It expects parameters to be  have been pushed on the stack.

You call it with:

```
newX = neldermead (data,  &function1, F1A1, F1A2, F1A3, F1A4, F1A5, 10, 10000);
```

You are not passing parameters to the function. When it returns, it returns to wrong address.

Comment: no, neldermead calls function1 for a variety of int values.